# Understanding that kelvins statement of the second law

Tags: thermodynamics, work, entropy

I am having a bit of trouble understanding the inequality given below:

[image]

Fig 13.10(b):
[image]

I am guessing that it looks as though all the heat in is going to do work, hence the violation (although I cant see why as I'm not sure I fully understand the diagram), but why does that mean the system must do no net work on the surroundings? I don't see why this is the only way to prevent kelvins statement from being violated.

Full Section:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand the authors point. Fig a is already a Kelvin Plank violation. Fig b showing that the source of the heat for the violation is the heat rejected by a Carnot cycle doesn't seem to change a thing. That said,  I would only be able to speculate on what the author is trying to say with the inequality.

Comment: I'm not even sure I understand Fig b. For one thing, why doesn't it label the heat taken from T for the  Carnot cycle? For another, are  we to assume the top and bottom of the figure now comprise a single combined cycle? And if so, how is the bottom linked to the top?

Comment: I have updated my question to show the context in which the diagram was introduced

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to me. I can't get past the fact that Fig a shows no heat rejected to a reservoir.

Comment: I agree, however this is the recommended textbook for the course and its hard to assume a textbook has done something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying I find the author's presentation confusing and I’m still not sure I understand Fig b. That said, based on the inequality given, $\Delta W$ is negative which means work done on the system. Since it is negative the arrow can be reversed in the diagram and the sign of $\Delta W$ made negative.  See my diagrams below.

In order for $\Delta W$ to be the work of a refrigerator, I’m showing heat $Q_h$ delivered to $T$ which is equal to the heat taken by the Carnot engine from that reservoir.

I suggest then that the equality applies if the refrigerator is reversible, in which case the overall net work is zero, and that the inequality applies if the refrigerator is irreversible.

If the refrigerator is irreversible, it means the magnitude of $\Delta W$ to deliver the same amount of heat $Q_h$ to $T$ will be greater than that for the reversible refrigerator. That makes the left side of the equation negative. Using the $\Delta U=Q-W$ version of the first law, negative work would mean that net work is done on the combined system.

Now we can say that neither the Carnot engine nor the refrigeration engine violates Kelvin Plank, since both are working between two heat reservoirs.

Like I said, I don't understand Fig b, so my analysis is speculative may not be the basis of the inequality.

Hope this helps.

[image]